# What is the equivalent of /usr/share/misc on Solaris?

Tags: solaris, directory-structure

The Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard has the following to say:

> This directory contains miscellaneous architecture-independent files which don't require a separate subdirectory under /usr/share.

This leads me to ask, what is the equivalent to /usr/share/misc on Solaris? Is there none, would a directory with a single file do the best job?

Comment: Are you packaging an application to be distributed that need a shared directory or just building locally ?